# Regular Expression to match string in content but exclude in achor and image tag

Tags: javascript

I need regular expression by which I can match "my company" text in string. but it should not from image or anchor tag.

I am using like this but getting fail :

`/(?!]?>)(my company)(?![^<]?</a>)|(?!]?>)(my company)(?![^<]?</a>)/i`

The above matches "my company" which is there in figtitle="test my company  testing". This should not happen.

My String is like below:

`<img fid="32" class="imgClick img-report img-responsive" figkey="rId52" figtitle="test my company  testing"> my company <a src="http://my company"> my company</a>`

Trying here:
https://regexr.com/3ponu

Comment: Why not use DOMParser instead? Much more elegant

Comment: You can't write perfect regex parser for DOM element because DOM is not a regular language.

Comment: I want to do server side operation. Using mongoshell. Thats why looking for javascript expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got It..!

    `var companyName = 'XYZ Company';
    var findStr = '([\s|\r\n|>])(?!?>)('+companyName+')(?![^<]?</a>)([\s|\r\n|>])';
    var re = new RegExp(findStr,"gi");
    data = data.replace(re, replaceStr);`